# On wp-admin menu, the slider revolution option leads to a 404 error, page not found

Tags: plugins

I am using Martfury 1.6.6 and revolution slider 5.4.8.2

On wp-admin menu, the slider revolution option leads to a 404 error, page not found.

How can I sort this out?

Comment: try to be more expressive please? present the whole problem, errors you see, error logs etc...

Comment: There are no error logs... When you click on the slider revolution option on the menu in the wp-admin, it leads to error 404.

Comment: no errors in console? also try changing wp-debug as true in your wp-config.php file and check the errors

Comment: Nothing on errors console on cpanel

Comment: console of your browser. press F12